# Nodejs Mocha test failing Jenkins

Tags: mysql, node.js, jenkins, mocha.js

I am testing my db connection using mocha module of nodejs and the test is passing locally.

```
describe('Access to DB', function(){
   describe('#fail', function(){
        it('should return -1 because wrong credentials', function(done){
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'head',
                database: 'head'
            });
            connection.connect(done);
        });
    })
});
```

`./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./test/test.js` tests pass when I run this command.

But when I run my job using jenkins. The test fails with error:

`Access to DB #fail should return -1 because wrong credentials: [0m[31m     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306[0m[90m at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]`

My jenkins is instaled in different server and Node app in different one. I am comunication between them with SHA keys. Everything is working except for this test. mysql is not installed in jenkins server. Could that be the reason.

Comment: you are trying to connect to a mysql instance on the local machine. Try to replace 'localhost' with IP address/hostname of your DB machine. it

Comment: I tried but it shows timeout error and I have all the GRANT permissions in place and my bind-address is also commented